# Spring boot- RabbitMQ consumer keep on printing "Retrieving delivery for Consumer"

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-rabbit

Hi I am using Spring boot 1.3.5 along with starter RabbitMQ. In this project i am having a RabbitMQ consumer which consumes messages from a particular queue.But while running the application it keeps on printing below message in the console.while browsing in google i read setting heartBeat will resolve the issue but no luck for me,

```
14:08:14.892 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.a.r.l.BlockingQueueConsumer - Retrieving delivery for Consumer: tags=[{amq.ctag-rDkzcToXLMWqF4fFUIHS0A=notificationQueue}], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/,3), conn: Proxy@47914ea3 Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@1096fe75 [delegate=amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/], acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
14:08:14.913 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-3] DEBUG o.s.a.r.l.BlockingQueueConsumer - Retrieving delivery for Consumer: tags=[{amq.ctag-jxyjMKfw6heu77XVdYh3tw=notificationQueue}], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/,2), conn: Proxy@47914ea3 Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@1096fe75 [delegate=amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/], acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
14:08:14.917 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-2] DEBUG o.s.a.r.l.BlockingQueueConsumer - Retrieving delivery for Consumer: tags=[{amq.ctag-AcbX0R5eM-ukqWN0a_nrwA=notificationQueue}], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/,1), conn: Proxy@47914ea3 Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@1096fe75 [delegate=amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/], acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
14:08:15.893 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG o.s.a.r.l.BlockingQueueConsumer - Retrieving delivery for Consumer: tags=[{amq.ctag-rDkzcToXLMWqF4fFUIHS0A=notificationQueue}], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/,3), conn: Proxy@47914ea3 Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@1096fe75 [delegate=amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/], acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
```

It's ever ending.Kindly find the below consumer code:

**RabbitMqConfiguration.java**

```
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.EnableRabbit;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.config.SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.Jackson2JsonMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessageConverter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableRabbit
public class RabbitMqConfiguration{

@Autowired
private CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory;

@Value("${concurrent.consumers}")
public int concurrent_consumers;

@Value("${max.concurrent.consumers}")
public int max_concurrent_consumers;

@Bean
public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory() {
        SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(cachingConnectionFactory);
        factory.setConcurrentConsumers(concurrent_consumers);
        factory.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(max_concurrent_consumers);
        factory.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());
        return factory;
    }

@Bean
public MessageConverter jsonMessageConverter()
{
    final Jackson2JsonMessageConverter converter = new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    return converter;
}

}
```

**NotificationConsumer.java**

```
@Component
public class NotificationConsumer {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NotificationConsumer.class);

@Value("${notification.queue}")
public String notificationQueue;

@RabbitListener(id="notification",containerFactory="rabbitListenerContainerFactory",queues = "#{notificationQueue}")
public void handleNotificationMessage(Transaction transaction)
{
    System.out.println("Entered handleNotificationMessage::"+transaction.getId());
    System.out.println("Exit handleNotificationMessage::"+transaction.getData());

    logger.info("Entered handleNotificationMessage::", transaction.getId());
    logger.info("Exit handleNotificationMessage::", transaction.getData());
}

@Bean
public Queue notificationQueue() {
    return new Queue(notificationQueue, true, false, false);
}

}
```

**application.yml**

```
spring:
    rabbitmq:
        addresses: 127.0.0.1:5672
        adminAddresses: http://127.0.0.1:15672
        username: guest
        password: guest
        requested-heartbeat: 60

spring.rabbit.exchange: notification-exchange
notification.queue: notificationQueue
concurrent.consumers: 3
max.concurrent.consumers: 10
```

Message will be produced by another application and this application will only consume the message.

Your help should be appreciated.

As per Gary flipped the logger level from DEBUG to INFO resolved my issue.

```
logging:
    level:
        ROOT: INFO
```

Now i am getting following exception:

**15:21:24.925 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-2] WARN  o.s.a.r.l.ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler - Fatal message conversion error; message rejected; 
it will be dropped or routed to a dead letter exchange, if so configured: (Body:'{"id":"5784eed4f5a64b4d8663e706","clientIdentifier":"313131313131",
"data":"Sample data by vad","currentAction":{"state":{"status":"PENDING","errorCode":"404"},"data":"Sample data"},
"hasError":false,"errorMessage":""}'MessageProperties [headers={__TypeId__=com.global.produce.model.Transaction}, 
timestamp=null, messageId=null, userId=null, appId=null, clusterId=null, type=null, correlationId=null, replyTo=null, contentType=application/json, 
contentEncoding=UTF-8, contentLength=0, deliveryMode=PERSISTENT, expiration=null, priority=0, redelivered=false, receivedExchange=, 
receivedRoutingKey=notificationQueue, deliveryTag=1, messageCount=0])**

Anyone have any idea about this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's just a `DEBUG` log; change the log settings to INFO or WARN or ERROR.

Comment: Yes after flipped the logger level to INFO fixed the issue but this is not a flaw?

Comment: Now i am getting following exception **Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessageConversionException: failed to resolve class name. Class not found [com.global.produce.model.Transaction]** Do you have any idea about this error?Also you can see more details about this error in my updated question.

Comment: I don't think that we are able to understand what your project domain `com.global.produce.model.Transaction` class is and why you don't have it in classpath. We only can say that `__TypeId__` is a part of JSON serialization on the producer part. For proper deserialization you really have to have that class in the consumer classpath or you custom mapping to different domain: http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.6.0.RELEASE/reference/html/_reference.html#json-message-converter

Comment: RabbitMQ Producer converts the java object to json and in the **__TypeId__ ** attribute it updates the package of the Java object. While consuming the message it expects the java object in the same package but i have the java object in different package.Since this message will be consumed by different application we cannot keep the same package structure in all the application.Do we have any resolution for this?

Comment: `>but this is not a flaw` - no - DEBUG logging is for, err, debugging - this is often used to prove to people that the listener thread is stuck in their code - if you don't see these logs then something is wrong. You should not overload existing questions with new ones; start a new question.

Comment: @GaryRussell Thank you for your reply.sure i will raise a new question.